# Why don't slash commands work? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

Slash commands don't appear in the command tree. The error pops up in the console:

"discord.app_commands.errors.MissingApplicationID: Client does not have an application_id set. Either the function was called before on_ready was called or application_id was not passed to the Client constructor."

```
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
bot.remove_command("help")
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name = "test")
async def test(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hello!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id="ID"))

bot.run(config.TOKEN)
```

I tried to use `@app_command()` but the problem wasn't solved.

```
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
bot.remove_command("help")
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@app_command(name = "test")
async def test(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hello!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id="айди моего сервера"))

bot.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, never mix `discord.Client` and `commands.Bot`!

There are couple reasons why your code isn't working:

- you are missing `import discord`
- command `test(interaction):` needs to be replaced with `test(interaction: discord.Interaction)`
- syncing command is wrong AND instead of putting guild ID (intiger), you put guild name (string)!
  `await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id="айди моего сервера"))`

Here is a working code:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

class aclient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents=discord.Intents.all())
        self.synced = False

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        if not self.synced:
            await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id="YOUR GUILD ID"))
            self.synced = True
   
client = aclient()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name = "test")
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hello!")

client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Also make sure all intents are enabled [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Comment: 1.  It's a little part of my code. I don't miss ```import discord```
2. It's not necessary... 
3. Thank you, I didn't pay attention to data type. 
Your code don't work :(

https://imgur.com/kepjBpK

Comment: Code works for me. Not sure why it doesn't work for you. If you want, pm me on discord and maybe i can help you there. `xRedCrystalx#5165`